# Transformar string em json

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estou com dificuldade na hora de converter a `string {data}` em `Json`, eu recebo ela separada por virgula diversas vezes, gostaria de transformar ela em `Json` para coletar a primeira chave

```
var data = [ "$SP", "92", "00:01:36.340", "00:05:48.929\n" ];
var data = [ "$MT", "91", "00:00:34.187", "00:18:44.001\n" ];
```

o desejado seria:

```
{  
   "$SP":{  
      "0":92,
      "1":"00:01:36.340",
      "2":"00:05:48.929",
   }
},
{
   "$MT":{  
      "0":91,
      "1":"00:00:34.187",
      "2":00:18:44.001,
   }
}
```

Comment: A sua variável `data` na pergunta é uma array ou uma string?

Comment: é uma string, eu consigo criar um array a partir dela com split

Comment: Se puder editar a pergunta informando qual o retorno dessa string `data`.

Comment: Não entendi o pq de ter duas variáveis com o mesmo nome!

Comment: eu recebo essa string diversas vezes ou seja, a cada segundo tenho uma atualização dela, por isso o exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `for...in` você consegue montar esse JSON da forma que falou. Crie uma função e cada vez que receber a array `data` jogue-a para a função que irá adicionar novas entradas a um objeto pré-criado (ex, `var json = {}`). Veja:

```js
var json = {}; // crio o objeto principal

function addJson(data){
   var chave; // declaro a variável que será o nome do sub-objeto
   for(var i in data){
      if(i == 0){ // trata apenas o primeiro valor da array, que será o nome do sub-objeto
         chave = data[i]; // declaro a variável com o primeiro valor da array
         json[chave] = {}; // cria o objeto com o primeiro valor da array
      }else{
         json[chave][i-1] = data[i]; // adiciona as entradas seguindo a ordem dos índices a partir de 0
      }
   }
}

// primeiro array recebido para adicionar ao objeto "json"
var data = [ "$SP", "92", "00:01:36.340", "00:05:48.929\n" ];
addJson(data); // envia para a função

// segundo array recebido para adicionar ao objeto "json"
data = [ "$MT", "91", "00:00:34.187", "00:18:44.001\n" ];
addJson(data); // envia para a função

console.log(json);
console.log(json.$MT[0]);
```

Comment: perfeito!!, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que para isso teriam que ocorrer algumas mudanças.

Primeiro o seu `data` teria que ser um array com arrays e depois você precisaria criar uma função para converter o seu `data` em um objeto, sendo que sempre o primeiro elemento seria a chave.

Fiz um código rápido aqui, veja se você entende:

```js
var data = [
    [ "$SP", "92", "00:01:36.340", "00:05:48.929" ], 
    [ "$MT", "91", "00:00:34.187", "00:18:44.001" ]
];

Array.prototype.toJson = function() {
 var obj = {};
    
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
     var key = this[i].shift();
     obj[key] = this[i]; 
    }
    
    return obj;
};

console.log(data.toJson());
```

Answer (score 1):

Desculpe não poder comentar, então vou lançar uma nova resposta.
Não use a solução postada `Array.prototype.toJson = function() {/*...*/}`, isso irá criar uma propriedade enumerada em todos os objetos do tipo array. Veja o exemplo:

```js
Array.prototype.toJson = function() {
    var obj = {};    
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var key = this[i].shift();
        obj[key] = this[i]; 
    }    
    return obj;
}

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var key in arr) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Agora toda vez que você iterar sobre os indices de um array, você irá obter toJson, o que poderá te causar varias dores de cabeça, sem mencionar erros.

Para adicionar um novo método não enumerável a seus arrays, utilize esta declaração:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'toJson', {
    value: function (property, value) {
      let obj = {};
      for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        obj[this[i].shift()] = this[i]; 
      }
      return obj;
    }
});

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var key in arr) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Perceba que toJson não aparece mais como uma propriedade de seu array, esta é a forma segura de adicionar mais métodos a um objeto.